# angular.js: how can you load a remote html file, and populate one of it's elements with model's data?

Tags: angularjs

I have global ng-app declared on the HTML tag level. There's a static element, that get's handled by specific ng-controller. Now, at some point of page usage flow, a widget gets loaded into the DOM. Widget lands outside the ng-controller element. Question: how can I populate that widget with data from angular's model and keep it in sync?

Using this simple code doesn't work:

```
<select ng-model="files" ng-options="f.name for f in files">
    <option value="">Select File</option>
</select>
```

Worth saying, that the widget is only a part of large amount of content (i.e. page) that gets loaded dynamically, which is why I'm trying to avoid declaring a controller for each of 'pages', as it looks to be an overkill.

Comment: How do you load the Widget?

Comment: @jpmorin with `$("#container").load("page.html");`

Comment: I actually could go with viewl-controller pair, but I don't really know if its possible to load them on demand. With HTML load its quite easy, especially when amount of pages is dynamic!

Comment: I do not understand fully your situation, but did you consider the use of ng-include? You can dynamically load partials with a model. Also, I suggest that you never use jQuery for DOM manipulation in combination with Angularjs, you should always use directives.

Comment: Ye, I agree that i should avoid mixing jquery with angular. However, i don't know how to load views and controllers on demand, and I need to set up a dynamic routing, since amount of my pages changes quite often. So: i cannot declare all controllers inside one script file, cannot setup routing and so on. Is there a way to declare a controller function inside a view?

Comment: You can have a look at this (http://maxlab.fr/blog/2013/03/angularjs-requirejs-seed/) which uses RequireJS to load files according to a view, so you can have multiple files for your controllers.

Comment: You could also do dynamic routing with a MainCtrl that contains the logic to dispatch the views/controllers using the $location provider. There are many exemples on the web too. The idea is to do the routing to only that controller which take in charge the dynamic logic. But still, it does not resolve your issue with the dynamic script loading (see RequireJS for that).

Comment: Mercí @jpmorin, I'll try reading it, and as of MainCtrl suggestion — i will give it a go.